# Possible to access Apple Watch Ultra Depth Data?

Tags: swift, watch, depth

Does anyone know if it is possible to access the apple watch ultra depth data from diving?

Trying to find api access for this.

Comment: Seems like it's not currently possible: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/716919